# RAILS : Before_filter with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create a before_filter that redirects the user on an other page if the condition isn't true.

I have four models :

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :matches, through: :inscriptions
  has_many :inscriptions

class Inscription < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :match
  belongs_to :player

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :players, through: :inscriptions
  has_many :inscriptions

class Stat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
```

Each `player`can join a `match` by creating an `inscription`. Then, each `player` can notes the others as many time as they have played a match together, but not more.

I would like to prevent a `player` to be able to note an other player more times than the number of times they played together.

So I have :

```
def is_noteable?(player)
    @matchs_du_joueur = Inscription.where(:player_id => current_user.id) 
    #all the `inscriptions` of a `match` from current_user

     @joueur = Player.joins(:inscriptions).where(:inscriptions => { :match_id => @matchs_du_joueur.map(&:match_id)}).group(:player_id).where('player_id <> ?', current_user.id)
    #all the `players`  that have played with `current_user`

    @combien_de_truc = Inscription.where(:match_id => @matchs_du_joueur.map(&:match_id), :player_id => @player.id).count 
    #to know how many `inscriptions` they have in a common `match`

    @combien_de_notes = Stat.where(:player_id => @player.id, :auteur => current_user.id).count 
    #to know how many times `current_user` has noted the player

    @combien_de_notes <= @combien_de_truc 
    #if `current_user` has  noted `player` less time than he played with him


    end
```

But this doesn't function as I want... It seems that there are no limits.

I hope you'll understand me. Thank you for reading me.

Comment: What is Inscription for?

Comment: Inscription means "registration". It is for register  in a match. Do you understand what I mean ?

Comment: Right off the bat, I think you may be using the wrong variable on the third and fourth query. Your function accepts a parameter (`player`), but on the lines where you set `@combien_de_truc` and @combien_de_notes`, you are using the variable `@player`, which is not the same as `player`. Could that be the cause?